# System login.service failed on ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: systemd-logind

The system was running perfect until i try to start it today and it shows this problem "system login.service failed". then it shows to run the following command "systemctl status systemd-logind.service". i have the access to root through advance recovery mode. it returns the status of systemd-logind.service is inactive (dead). On ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Please help me to solve this error. Thank you.

Comment: Does your system boot ? Can you type commands ? In wich shell ? Try to type sudo login

Comment: JerareYoshi yes the system boot but i am not able to login coz it does not display the login interface. i can type commands on root shell in advaced recovery mode. what do i do after i type login